# How to make a scatterplot/bubble chart in R including continuous an discrete variables from two matrices

Tags: r, charts, scatter-plot

I have two data matrices (this is an example):

matrix 1: genotypes (na es missing data)

```
NA NA HOM HET HOM
NA NA HOM HET HOM
NA NA HOM HET HOM
NA NA HOM HET HOM
NA NA HOM HET HET
```

matrix 2: read counts

```
0 0 1 2 2
0 0 1 2 2
0 0 1 2 2
0 0 1 2 3
0 0 1 2 3
```

I would like to create a scatterplot/bubble chart in R similar to this drawing:

[image]

Comment: That's not a scatterplot, that's a bubble chart. If I understand your question correctly, you need to combine m1 and m2 and then aggregate it in order to create your plot. Correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's another answer. It is similar, but has some differences with the approach taken by Rawr, mainly that I've assumed the data to be matrices (and not dataframes) and used another plotting engine.

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
#combine the data, as we need to be able to count each occurence of combinations
#assumes data are in matrices. converts to dataframe because of different types
mydat <- data.frame(geno=as.vector(geno),
                    readcount=as.vector(readcounts))


#remove missings
mydat <- mydat[!is.na(mydat$geno),]


#aggregate using reshape

plotdata <- dcast(geno+readcount~"count", 
data=mydat, fun.aggregate = length, value.var="readcount")

#plot

p1 <- ggplot(plotdata, aes(x=readcount,y=geno)) +
  geom_point(aes(size=count)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=1:3)+
  theme_bw()
p1
```

[image]

Comment: Fantastic!, Thanks for that solution. I even prefer to use ggplot. But the real dataset was much larger and bubbles don't work very well. Could you please indicate how to transform the bubble chart in a bar chart? With two coloured bars one for HET and other for HOM. Thanks again!

Comment: That's a different question.